# Need help creating a .bat file to execute SAS jobs

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Using Windows 7, I need a .bat file that will execute files in a folder whenever I put them in there. for example I want it to execute files with a .sas suffix and then rename them once executed. I want toe programs to run in sequence, not simultaneously. I am rusty on my bat programming.

I can get the following to run,

```
cd C:\Users\ABC\Dropbox\XYZ\Runlibrary
timeout /t 15
"C:\Program Files\SASHome2-94\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe"  -sysin  "program5.sas"
ren "program5.sas" "program5.done"
```

but now want a loop and the ability to have it do all .SAS programs in the folder. Something like

```
do (the following 1 million times) 
timeout /t 15
for %f in (*.sas) do "C:\Program Files\SASHome2-94\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe"  -sysin  "%f"
for %f in (*.sas) do ren "*.sas" "*.done"
```

Thoughts, links or sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that I cooked up, I haven't tested any of this, but give it a whirl as it's supposed to loop until you kill it:

```
@echo off
:: Setting max_count to '0' makes this an infinite loop, you can set it to 10000000 if you want or leave it at 0
set max_count=0

:: Location where the .sas files are stored; '.' means current directory
set sas_dir=.

:: counter should be '0' 
set counter=0

:: Starting the loop
:start_loop
set /a counter+=1

:: Looking for .sas files to execute
if exist "%sas_dir%\*.sas" for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /o:n /a:-d "%sas_dir%\*.sas"') do (
    echo INFO: Running %%f
    call "C:\Program Files\SASHome2-94\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe" -sysin "%%~pnxf"
    rename "%%~pnxf" "%%~pnf.done"
)

:: Stats
echo INFO: Looped Count: %counter%; Reloop Time: 15 secs

:: Waiting 15 secs to reloop
timeout /t 15 >nul

:: Checking Max Counter
if "%max_count%"=="%counter%" (
    echo INFO: Looping completed with "%max_count%" counts, exiting...
    goto end
)

:: relooping
goto start_loop

:end
```

Here's a site that I found to be informative on `for` loops and other batch related questions: http://judago.webs.com/batchforloops.htm